# how to get a specific character from input?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char, getchar

i done a tutorial about getchar: 
[getChar - c++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/)

this all worked till i wanted to make some modifications.

```
char c;
puts("enter . to exit");
do{
    c=getchar();

} while (c != '.'); {

    if(c == 's'){
        upgradeOne();
        cout << "upgrade1 is done" << endl;
}

    if (c == 'a'){
        upgradeTwo();
        cout << "upgrade2 is done" << endl;
    }
}

while (total < 999){
    total += i;
    cout << total << endl;
}
```

i want to use specific methods when the user input equels an specific character.
if the user types a the method upgradetwo() must be activated.
how am i supposed to do this?

Comment: You can't break out of the do/while loop. It's always looking for a period.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't help you.

Comment: Once again, the solution would be trivial if OP indented its code properly.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood where the body of a do-while loop is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repetitive processing of your input takes place in the `do...while` loop. The loop is left only when `'.'` is pressed.

If you want to react on specific chars, you have to move your `if(c==...)` statements into this loop (i.e. Between the `getchar()` and the `while`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the loop until the user enters period(.), then you can use some bool flag which will be set to true initially. Then write a while which will run until the flag is false. In the while read the character and if it is a period then set the flag to false.

or you can run the while loop infinitely and break the loop if the char is a period else continue.